# AttributeError: type object 'Transaction' has no attribute 'exclude'

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, ethereumjs

When I execute a python script to deploy smart contracts, it throws the following exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "contrCompDeploy.py", line 7, in <module>
    from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
  File "/home/fabric/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from eth_account import Account  # noqa: E402
  File "/home/fabric/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_account/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from eth_account.account import Account  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/fabric/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_account/account.py", line 40, in <module>
    from eth_account.signing import (
  File "/home/fabric/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_account/signing.py", line 9, in <module>
    from eth_account.transactions import (
  File "/home/fabric/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_account/transactions.py", line 101, in <module>
    UnsignedTransaction = Transaction.exclude(['v', 'r', 's'])
AttributeError: type object 'Transaction' has no attribute 'exclude'
```

and the related python codes are:

```
import _pysha3  
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
```

Comment: I have never met such an error and I don't know where the problem comes from. Please help me

Comment: You get that error when you code is only `import _pysha3` and `from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider`???

Comment: No! I mean the exception is thrown when these lines are executed. Specifically, the second line. Please the `Traceback'

Comment: Something in your installation is not right. Either the web3 package, or python itself. Try to uninstall and then reinstall (and if I may suggest, upgrade from python 3.6 to python 3.9 while you're at it).

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks very much! Your suggestions worked! I upgraded python 3.6 to python 3.8 but did not work, but when I upgrade to python 3.9, it worked

Answer (score 0):

**Go to \site-packages\eth_account\transactions.py and change**

```
UnsignedTransaction = Transaction.exclude(['v', 'r', 's'])
```

**to this**

```
del_attr_list = ['v', 'r', 's']
UnsignedTransaction = Transaction
[delattr(UnsignedTransaction, attr) for attr in del_attr_list]
```